# how to get backtrace information for php errors in drush

Tags: 7, drush

I want to get backtrace information for php errors in drush.

Tried out the following patch - http://drupal.org/node/1158322#comment-6249880. Its shows the backtrace info as message(while using browser), but I'm not getting these messages in drush

Comment: You could install xdebug to get stack traces. http://www.anilsagar.com/blog/debug-drupal-using-xdebug-eclipse-and-wamp

Comment: Bugs / feature requests should be reported in the issue queue for the involved module.

Comment: doesn't seem off topic according to the scope defined in the help center. Firstly: "Questions are acceptable as long as they require specific Drupal expertise to be answered." Secondly, although the scope states that you should raise issues on Drupal.org, it doesn't say that you can't raise a question on the same issue.  Make the scope clearer, or make it clear why this (good and worthwhile) question is out of scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be posted as a Feature Request in the Drush issue queue.  I started that off for you here:  http://drupal.org/node/1804600

Comment: I'm sorry that my efforts in the issue queue were not more fruitful.  :(

Comment: New issue opened in https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/393

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the old-school way:

drush_log(print_r(debug_backtrace()), 'error')